# What can be a database in mysql as a minor project?

Tags: database

Some ideas about making a database in mysql as a minor project for the students.

Comment: Are you talking about all specific tables that should be create in a database like this or in mysql configuration?

Comment: This is unclear.

Comment: I mean what should be my main database n what tables should be there?

Answer (score 1):

How about databases regarding:

- Simple e-banking if u go into stored procedures
- Company with 2 sites, employees, customers with orders, orders can have multiple articles etc
- A blog with authors, categories
- A forum
- Support ticketing system
- Online shop
- etc

Think about real life use cases, I didn't like imaginary tasks.

If I misunderstood your question, be more clear what you want.

Comment: Your ideas are helpful. I meant to get the same suggestions. Thanks